# What is an amenity?

Tags: animal-crossing-pocket-camp

There is a challenge to finish an "amenity" but I don't see anything in the beginner's guide that defines what this is.

[image: Craft an amenity]

Is it the "elegant" style items?

[image: elegant]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer by accident: **"Amenities" are the large tents and other activities that can be built north of the campsite.** It should included anything under the tent icon in the crafting tab, based on the Catalog.

[image: Select an Amenity][image: Crafting Complete][image: Catalog]